# Salesforce to Salesforce integration via outbound message

Tags: integration, soap, workflowoutboundmessage

I am working first time on integration. I have two salesforce system A & B. System A has an object P with  some custom fields. System B wants to send some fields values using outbound message and i need to create record of P in system A using those fields values.What would be the approach to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Your simplest solution is to implement Salesforce-to-Salesforce.

Otherwise, you'll need to pass a recordId and a sessionId to the 2nd Salesforce instance which it can then use to retrieve the record updates from the 1st Salesforce instance by calling for the object with that recordId while using the same sessionId to authenticate (unless you have other security measures in place that will allow the Org to log-in to your org to obtain the record updates).

Comment: @crmprogdev-I need to retrieve values from outbound message which is being sent by other system to my system and with those values i need to create a record of object P. I need to write outbound message listener in my salesforce org.am i going right ?

Comment: Outbound messages typically don't contain all of the detailed information that you might think. Instead, often they'll only contain the recordId and a notification that field level change was made without all the details on the fields and values involved. There's also no guarantee that they're received. It's best to have the receiving org do a callback to get the updated information unless you're sending the outbound message as an email which you can parse to perform the update. Much depends on the services handling the connection between orgs.

Comment: I need to consume outbound message from one salesforce org to another salesforce org. Any sample code for such listener class would help me which can take input as outbound message.